# in app purchase issue in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have created an app with in app purchase and tested it with `CurrentAppSimulator` and works fine but when i create the package for app it fails

This is my code for which i am creating package

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InAppInit()
{

    var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();

    // Delux Unlock - Durable
    var unlockFeatureDelux = listing.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value.ProductId == "deluxe" && p.Value.ProductType == ProductType.Durable);
    isDeluxPurchased = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[unlockFeatureDelux.Value.ProductId].IsActive;
    deluxProductID = unlockFeatureDelux.Value.ProductId;

    // Standard Unlock - Durable
    var unlockFeatureStandard = listing.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value.ProductId == "standard" && p.Value.ProductType == ProductType.Durable);
    isStarndardPurchased = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[unlockFeatureStandard.Value.ProductId].IsActive;
    standardProductID = unlockFeatureStandard.Value.ProductId;

}
```

I am calling this method `OnLaunched` in `App.xaml.cs`

Comment: Fails how? errors? invalid results?

Comment: as I know, work with Store is horrible :) It often falls. At first, you can wrap your code in try\catch

Comment: Care to share what that exception is?..

Comment: actually in store app you create a package that should pass different tests and my app fails in 'onapplaunch' test.

Comment: it is not getting the in app purchase ids

Comment: Maybe unlockFeatureDelux.Value and unlockFeatureStandard.Value are null, because they are not purchased at that point?  ...you don't even handle the case when they are not purchased in your code snippet

Comment: Exception from HRESULT: 0x801900CC this is the exception

Comment: @gregkalapos it works fine with CurrentAppSimulator but package fails with actual values

Comment: The other option is of course that LoadListringInformationAsync does not return the two values which you select. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.loadlistinginformationasync

Comment: I think you have to define your IAP in the store. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219684.aspx Step 4. Did you do that? Plus of course you have to associate your package with your app where your defined the IAP. I could imagine that otherwise LoadListingInformationAsync returns an empty list (FIXME)

Comment: Attn: Mr. @gregkalapos.
Yes, I have created the IAP in the store already.
the problem is in create package duration. (by Waqas Shah Mashwani)
If I remove the InApp feature then the App work fine, but this happen with InApp during creation of Package. 
Yes, App is already associated with Store.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know what is in the ProductListings list. If you do this:  var plist = listing.ProductListings; var keys = plist.Keys.ToList(); and run this code... what is in it?

Comment: ...i mean what is in the keys list?

Comment: @gregkalapos it returns null and generate this exception that i mentioned before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our discussion here is what I would do:

- The `LoadListingInformationAsync` method uses internet and if the user does not have an internet connection then it will throw an exception. So I suggest to wrap this whole stuff into a try/ctach block
- As we see the `ProductListings` does not contain any item. I don't know how this list is populated, but as long as your app is not in the store I would not be surprised when that list is empty (Maybe someone can help out here... but i did not find anything regarding this in the docs). So for this I would just simply check if the feature you need is in the list... With this your package will pass the test you mentioned and you can upload it. If the list is also empty when the package is installed via the store, then something with the IAP setting is wrong (but that is related to the store..)
- And a general comment: Obviously this code is not complete... You need some code for purchasing the IAPs and here we only get the Ids.. (But I think you only pasted the relevant part anyway.)

So all this in code:

```
 public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InAppInit()
    {
        try
        {
            var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
            if (listing.ProductListings.ContainsKey("deluxe"))
            {
                // Delux Unlock - Durable
                var unlockFeatureDelux = listing.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value.ProductId == "deluxe" && p.Value.ProductType == ProductType.Durable);
                isDeluxPurchased = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[unlockFeatureDelux.Value.ProductId].IsActive;
                deluxProductID = unlockFeatureDelux.Value.ProductId;
            }
            else
            {
                //There is no deluxe IAP defined... so something with your IAP stuff is wrong...
            }

            if (listing.ProductListings.ContainsKey("standard"))
            {
                // Standard Unlock - Durable
                var unlockFeatureStandard = listing.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value.ProductId == "standard" && p.Value.ProductType == ProductType.Durable);
                isStarndardPurchased = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[unlockFeatureStandard.Value.ProductId].IsActive;
                standardProductID = unlockFeatureStandard.Value.ProductId;
            }
            else
            {
                //same as for Delux
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Show  this on the UI...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it solved my problem now i will check it over a beta version if it works or not

Comment: You might want to look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148828/adcontrol-does-not-show-ads-with-pub-center-app-id-and-unit-id

Comment: I think then it should be store related. The next step would be to look again into your IAP settings in the store. From some reason the app does not seem to get the IAP list... you should figure out why