# Adcontrol does not show ads with pub center App id and Unit id

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have an Adcontrol which works fine with test values given by Msdn but does not shows ads with actual values.(Windows Store App)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a perfectly normal behaviour if there is no ad to display. 
You can suscribe to the [ErrorOccured event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-adcontrol-erroroccurred-event(v=msads.20).aspx) of the AdControl and check the Error property to confirm that by seeing a "No fill" message.